# How to display image with OpenViewerFX

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-viewer, openviewerfx

I am using the OpenViewerFX component to display PDF files in
my JavaFX application.

https://github.com/IDRSolutions/maven-OpenViewerFX-src

I managed to do so without a problem, but
I also need to display image files in the viewer.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){

    this.openViewerFX = new OpenViewerFX(pdfViewer,null);

    this.openViewerFX.setupViewer();

    Object[] images = new Object[]{"1542480001.tif"};
    openViewerFX.executeCommand(Commands.OPENFILE,images);
}
```

I have tried the code above but it doesn't seem to open the image files.

Is it possible to use the OpenViewerFX library to display images as well,
or is it only restricted to PDF files?

Thanks in advance